# Angularjs $urlRouterProvider.otherwise not working with MVC5 until page refresh

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angular-ui-router

I am working on a mvc5 application (not spa) but in one of my pages, I am creating a multi step form and chose angular. Everything is working if I refresh the page, but when I click on the link that redirects me to my page with angular, the ui-router is not working.

index.chtml

```
<div class="row" ng-app="formApp">
    <!-- views will be injected here -->
    <div ui-view></div>

</div>

<script>
    require(["angular", "ngAnimate", "ui.router"], function (angular, ngAnimate, router) {
        angular.module('formApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router'])
            // configuring our routes 
            // =============================================================================
            .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

                $stateProvider

                    // route to show our basic form (/form)
                    .state('form', {
                        url: '/form',
                        templateUrl: "/AutoAccident/Form",
                        controller: 'formController'
                    })

                    // nested states 
                    // each of these sections will have their own view
                    // url will be nested (/form/profile)
                    .state('form.profile', {
                        url: '/profile',
                        templateUrl: "/AutoAccident/FormProfile",
                    })

                    // url will be /form/interests
                    .state('form.interests', {
                        url: '/interests',
                        templateUrl: "/AutoAccident/FormInterests",
                    })

                    // url will be /form/payment
                    .state('form.payment', {
                        url: '/payment',
                        templateUrl: "/AutoAccident/FormPayment",
                    });

                // catch all route
                // send users to the form page 
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/profile');
            })
            // our controller for the form
            // =============================================================================
            .controller('formController', function ($scope) {

                // we will store all of our form data in this object
                $scope.formData = {};

                // function to process the form
                $scope.processForm = function () {
                    alert('awesome!');
                };

            });
    });
</script>
```

My issue is that when i go to //mydevurl/AutoAccident/Index which triggers the code above, I am getting

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=formApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:nomod%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.5%2F$injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DformApp%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:24:78%0A%20%20%20%20at%20a%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:23:141)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:23:384%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:37:332%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:37:180)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:40:435)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:51416%2FScripts%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:19:381,

but when I try to refresh by clicking refresh button of my browser, the app works and my URI becomes http://mydevurl/AutoAccident/Index#/form/profile automatically and shows my multi step form.

Same error when I click my menu. My multistep form is not the default page when my app loads.

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "AutoAccident")">Auto Accident</a></li>
```